# autoload в composer (psr-4)

Tags: php, composer, autoload

Ошибка: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Core\DB' not found in**

composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "klein/klein": "^2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

Структура файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример namespace:

```
src/Core/DB.php - namespace App\Core;  
src/Models/Offer.php - namespace App\Models;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
А если так:

"psr-4": {
    "App\\Core\\": "src/Core/",
    "App\\Controllers\\": "src/Controllers/",
    "App\\Models\\": "src/Models/"
}
```